# How to remove items from the admin bar

Tags: apostrophe-cms

The [Apostrophe CMS](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/tutorials/howtos/admin-bar) is clear enough on how to add items to the admin bar.

I am trying to remove items (some pieces that we have created) so that we can choose who sees what.

I tried setting an empty array to remove every object

```
'apostrophe-admin-bar': {
  items: [],
  ...
}
```

to no avail.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague and I figured it out. In the `index.js` of the piece, add this:

```
construct(self, options) {
  if (self.name === 'pieceNameGoesHere' {
    self.addToAdminBar = Function.prototype;
  }
}
```